# Not able to push code in Git from Travis CI cloud for node

Tags: node.js, github, travis-ci

I have already gone through the previous post related to my problem and I checked every steps described there. But till my problem does not get the solution.
1)I am trying to use Travis CI cloud (not any CLI client as I have to only work with cloud)with Github login for public repository for end to end integration for node project.
2) After test with Travis I use the Istanbul for code coverage and push back to Git the coverage report which will be further use by Sonar cloud.
3) The link for my project and travis.yml : https://github.com/arpitajava/ZynlaNew
4) I have created the personal token in Git Hub for Travis and set as GH_TOKN as env variable in Travis page as well as .travis.yml
5) Every steps in the .travis.yml file is executing fine expect the last step git push.

> $ git commit -m "Travis build"  Travis build 
>   16 files changed, 1951 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-) It is showing that
>   it committed 17 files after git commit execution.

$ git push origin

> master remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication
>   failed for 'https://github.com/arpitajava/ZynlaNew.git/' Done. Your
>   build exited with 0.

Comment: You need to mention the `GH_TOKEN` in the github url itself.